# Concat two method calls in javascript

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax

I have method what I use into all my code to populate dropdown lists like:

```
function FillSelectCatalog(method, controlName, valueName, textName, assignValue) {
    try {
        $(function () {
            $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                type: "post",
                dataType: "json",
                url: '../Catalogo/' + method,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (response) {
                    FillSelect(controlName, response, valueName, textName, assignValue);
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    ErrorMessage("Error", GetTextError(response));
                }
            });
        });
    } catch (e) {
        ErrorMessage("Error", e.message);
    }
}
```

So with jQuery I call my dropdown something like:

```
FillSelectCatalog("GetActiveMeter", "meterEnergy", "Id", "Meter1", null);
```

In dropdown I get something like

```
meterEnegry1, 
meterEnergy2, 
etc
```

and I want to concat with another FillSelectCatalog to get something like `"meterEnergy1 - Water"`, is that possible?

There is my another FillSelectCatalog with "Water" value I want to concat:

```
 FillSelectCatalog("GetMeterType", "meterType", "MeterTypeId", "Description", null);
```

Controller:

```
[Authorize]
        public string GetActiveMeter()
        {
            string toReturn = string.Empty;
            var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            var currentUser = UserClass.GetUserBranchOfficeId(userId);
            try
            {
                IGenericRepository<Meter> entity = new GenericRepository<Meter>();
                IGenericRepository<MeterType> entity2 = new GenericRepository<MeterType>(); //there is Water value in column Description

                var result = entity.GetList(x => x.Status).Where(x => x.BranchOfficeId == currentUser);

                toReturn = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(result);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            return toReturn;
        }
```

`"Water"` value is into another table called `MeterType` in column called `Description`
Regards

Comment: Instead of making 2 calls, why not update one server method to return the concatenated text.

Comment: Can you help me how can I update this method to accept concat? @Shyju

Comment: You need to share the code of the method

Comment: It´s in my question right now @Shyju

Comment: Does your `Meter` type have a property `MeterType` on it (or `Type`)?

Comment: `Metr` has a `MeterTypeId (Foreign Key)` @RobertMcKee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[Authorize]
public string GetActiveMeter()
{
    string toReturn = string.Empty;
    var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    var currentUser = UserClass.GetUserBranchOfficeId(userId);
    try
    {
        IGenericRepository<Meter> entity = new GenericRepository<Meter>();
        var result = entity
          .GetList(x=>x.State, x => x.MeterType)
          .Where(x=>x.BranchOfficeId==currentUser)
          .Select(x=>new { Id = x.Id, Meter1 = x.Meter1 + ' - " + x.MeterType.Description});

        toReturn = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(result);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    return toReturn;
}
```

Comment: I need to add all columns of table  into select? because I´m getting null reference

Comment: Only the columns you need to return for your web app.  Here I'm just returning two -- Id And Meter1.  The null reference might be coming from trying to get the MeterType or Description out of your Repository.  Your repository might not support (or may require a different method call) to get child objects than what I've provided.  This would work if your repository is just a wrapper around Entity Framework, and your data model is set up that way, but I can't tell you that.  Try putting a breakpoint and see what `entity` has for methods and properties.

Comment: Ya, you give me an idea  and it works, I explain it... My method GetList accept boolean and an Include so I include MeterType and It works, I should modified your answer

Comment: Ok, I accepted your edit.  With EF you don't need to Include columns that are explicitly mentioned in query, but it appears your GetList isn't returning an IQueryable (or an IQueryable wrapping an IEnumerable), so the auto-include doesn't work.  Good to see whoever did the GetList routine did allow for manual includes though!  Of course this also likely means that the are returning an IEnumerable, which isn't the best for performance (it forces all columns to be returned, which will bypass some indexes), but that's a different topic.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly maintain some `mySelectValues[]` somewhere and insert the values in as they come. For Meter1 you could prepend and for others you could just append.

```
var mySelectValues = [];
function FillSelectCatalog(method, controlName, valueName, textName, assignValue) {
    try {
        $(function () {
            $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                type: "post",
                dataType: "json",
                url: '../Catalogo/' + method,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (response) {
                    if (testName == 'Meter1') { 
                        mySelectValues.unshift(response);
                    } else {
                         mySelectValues.push(response);
                    }
                    FillSelect(controlName, response, valueName, textName, assignValue);
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    ErrorMessage("Error", GetTextError(response));
                }
            });
        });
    } catch (e) {
        ErrorMessage("Error", e.message);
    }
}
```